# Insert a mongo doc if timestamp of existing doc older than a preset time - using upsert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, upsert

I have a requirement to update an existing doc if it's updated time is not older than 1 minute from now. I have the below query but it still goes ahead and updates the existing document no matter what. How do I fix this behaviour?

```
threats.upsert({
                threatType: threatLevel,
                username: userOrDeviceName,

                "misc.updatedTime": {$lt: new Date(new Date() - 60000)}
}, {
                $set: {
                    'misc.updatedTime': new Date(),
                    'misc.updatedBy': 'system',

                },
                $addToSet: {
                    serverAddr: { $each: destinations }
                },
                $inc: {
                    flowCount: destinations.length
                },
                $setOnInsert: {
                    threatState: "open",
                    'misc.createdTime': new Date(),
                    'misc.createdBy': 'system',

                }
            }
```

Comment: Mongoose I presume? If so then `threats` appears to be an **instance** that you retrieved via `find()` or `findOne()`. If you have the instance then you have the data at hand, so simply **do not update it**. For commands like `updateOne()` or `findOneAndUpdate()` you would simply add to the query predicate to not select a document which does not meet the date constraint. But since you already have the **instance data**, then you check the property in code and simply **do not issue the update**.

Comment: I'm using this as part of a meteor app actually. Not using mongoose.

Comment: Same basic concept anyway. The lack of a "query predicate" on the function tells me you already have an instance in memory. There's no MongoDB function to look at a value and decide whether or not to apply an update as an "update operator". As I said, **normally** we would exclude the document with a query predicate. However you already pulled the data from the server. So just test the property before you decide to update or not. Simple.